# pass single value to three diffrent iframe

Tags: javascript, html

can anybody tell me how to pass any sngle value to three diffrent iframe withhout using any server lang. like java or php.So it means only javascript or html???
please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadVal(val) {
  window.frames[0].location='somehtml.html?val='+val;
  window.frames[1].location='somehtml.html?val='+val;
  window.frames[2].location='somehtml.html?val='+val;
  return false;
}
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="return loadVal('This is a value')">Click</a>
```

In the receiving pages you can get the value from location.search

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set javascript variables that are local to each iframe:

```
window.frames[0]['foo']='bar';
window.frames[1]['foo']='car';
window.frames[2]['foo']='par';
```

A little more information could help us better answer your question.